# Suggestions for an encryption scheme

Tags: c#, aes, rsa

I have a client which is distributing music to businesses. He has the distribution rights and all the legal stuff is taken care of. I am building a media player for him that will support encrypted files. This is done so that the music cannot be transferred by the business to a third party.

I have already done some research and implemented a scheme where the large files are encrypted with an AES symmetrical key and the symmetrical key is encrypted with an RSA public key and the player decrypts the AES key with the RSA private key. I already got this working.

My problem is that with this setup, the private key is in the player side (in a certificate) and can be copied to another machine along with the player and files.
I would like to add another layer to this scheme to make it tougher.
I am new to these type of security implementations. Are there any known schemes for this?

btw: I'm using C#/WPF for the player.

Comment: You still have the analog copy problem (assuming someone gets to _listen_ to it), which only one person needs to "solve" and the music is released to the wild.  Focus on content and getting those who are willing to pay a quick, reliable way of doing so.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - As I have commented on the bellow question, this is not a choice, and even if it was, it is not mine to make. I'm just a freelance developer doing the project.

Comment: Are you absolved from any legal issues if (when) this fails?  This doesn't sound like a project I would take on without some sort of protection...

Comment: @AustinSalonen - Yes I am. I had my lawyer make sure of that before I even went in to this.

Comment: As you are discovering the hard part of encryption is not writing the code, it is *managing the keys*. People often fall in love with the math and forget that the math *assumes that the keys are managed securely*. The problem space you're in is not one where encryption is a particularly good fit for this reason. And yet people continue to try.

Comment: Your problem is like giving someone the key of a safebox, asking them to open the safebox **just once**, and pretend that they will only look at the contents without taking anything.

Comment: If you have an answer to my question, by all means, go a head and answer. I will be very thankful! But please spare me the lectures. I am not a 5 year-old and I have no choice in the matter. I am just creating a solution for a client as per their request.

Comment: @EricLippert - Yes, that is quickly becoming very apparent... But since this is the project I was hired for, I'll do my best. It`s funny to me that everyone acts like they never did anything for a client they were not 100% in agreement with. Or maybe it`s just me and my weak principles.

Comment: @EladLachmi: It's not a question of the morality of DRM. The question here is a technical one: is it possible to do the job that the client is hiring you to do? And the answer is: in hardware, yes, but not in software. If the supposedly "private" key is in software and is actually in the possession of the attacker then you've already lost. If you want to make the argument that the attacker is unsophisticated then you don't need strong encryption in the first place; ROT13 will do.

Comment: If there are moral questions here, they are: (1) have you represented yourself as an expert on strong crypto security schemes, which plainly you are not?  (Hey, I'm not either, but I'm not trying to write a security system, you are.) and (2) is the client aware that they are asking for something that is basically impossible?

Comment: @EricLippert - Both good questions. (1) I did not. I have been working with this client on other projects, and so I was also selected for this one. (2) Yes, the client is well aware. The organization providing the copyright is saying "We have no idea what needs to be done. We have no standard for protecting digital data, but we want you to make your "best effort" to protect the copyright material."

Comment: @EladLachmi: This is not really a good question for this site, as I suspect you are now aware.

Comment: @GregS - This is ridiculous! For some time now people around here have gotten on their high horse and they just don't know how to get off. It's becoming harder and harder to get a technical answer to a technical question. People are more interested in teaching you how to live then helping you with your question.

Comment: @EladLachmi: Maybe you're right. In my opinion (from the top of my high horse) DRM design questions in particular should be called out as not appropriate. They inevitably result in discussions that have the characteristic of a "not constructive" question. As the FAQ says, "...this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion..."

Comment: @GregS - I appreciate your opinion and please understand that the high horse comment was not a personal comment about you, but my point is that the fact that DRM is unpopular should have no bearing on the quality of technical solutions presented. I considered this might be an issue when posting. Maybe I gave this community more credit than it deserves. Maybe I should have exchanged music for some other type of file. Would that make it a more appropriate question?

Comment: And I am sorry for any feelings hurt by my comments. I think we all went way off point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypted music = lame.

Other than that there's always a hole when you're talking about media, because one can always tap the analog signal. If you manage to put some tough-to-crack scheme there I wouldn't even bother with it and just loop in the audio out to in, record from there and re-broadcast. There are known schemes and there are known cracks for all of them.

BUT if you really insist a more "secure" approach would be to generate a random key per customer. On the customer side you can use DPAPI to store the public part so it can't be easily copied to other machines.

You could do that with either symmetric or asymmetric encryption, keeping the private key on the server. The latter requires humongous processing power, likely unfeasible, the former still requires strong server.

Either way - it's a waste of time but I get it that there may be legal language that requires you to provide such functionality

Comment: As you stated, this is not a choice. It's part of the distribution agreement he signs with the people representing the artists. He has to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this is a problem with no real technological solution, which is why the DMCA exists. iTunes tries to do something similar, except that the personal key is retrieved from an online store and then saved locally encrypted with a key that is partially based on some kind of machine identifier they have devised - which the DMCA makes illegal to reverse engineer. Since not everybody respects the law all the time, they have repeatedly changed the way in which they compute that key.

Comment: Well, truth-be-told, I am looking at a very narrow audience, which is not very technologically savvy. I just want to make it a little more than obvious.

Comment: If that's the case, just generate a random machine key on install or first run, and store it in some obscure part of the filesystem.